# CSS - fill remaining space of float containing element with text input that has set min-width

Tags: html, css

I need behavior when text input will fill remaining horizontal space in its parent. Text input must be vertically on same position as float element. It must respect own min-width, so when `available space in parent < min-width of text input`, then text input must starts under all floated elements and fill horizontally whole containing block. Is that possible with css?

```
<div style="width:300px;background-color:aqua">
   <div style="float:left;background-color:gray">content</div>
   <input type="text" style="width: ???;min-width:150px" />
</div>
```

EDIT: i need to know how set width of text input

http://jsfiddle.net/JrDHG/

Comment: I think if you reworded your question a tad bit more clearly - you could get some more help ^-^.

Comment: @LloanAlas: http://jsfiddle.net/JrDHG/5/ this is almost what i need, expect that input should by after all floats

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible, you can wrap the input into the block that establishes [new block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). It can be div with

```
overflow: hidden;
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JrDHG/2/))

box-sizing:border-box for input will be also useful, it helps the input to fit into this block with its default style (border, padding etc.).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to move min-width to this wrapper block: http://jsfiddle.net/JrDHG/4/

Comment: Looks like it's working to me. Why exactly doesn't fit the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Border-box is what you are after.

And also you need javascript for that.

```
input{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


 document.getElementById('input').setAttribute('style' , 'width:'+
 (document.getElementById('wrapper').offsetWidth - document.getElementById('div').offsetWidth) + 
 'px');
```

You can generalize this for multiple elements.

#### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/JrDHG/6/)

Comment: that is only simple abstract example of what i need. I don't know if it should be like that. Text input must fill REMAINING horizontal space after float elements.

Comment: @Krab you need javascript for this. Updated answer

Comment: i hope it is possible with css only